# Validation Forms without Entity with form class

Tags: php, symfony

I need help about validation forms without entity but with form class. My problem is the collection constraint in my form class in the override method getDefaultOoptions. It doesn't take this collection into account when I bind the form in my controller.

**This is my class form**

```
    namespace Projet\TicketBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class TicketPackAndAppType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('total', 'text' ,array('label' => 'Total de la commande  ',     'read_only' => true))


            ->add('address_delivery', 'entity' , array('class' => 'TacTill\CustomerBundle\Entity\Address',
                  'property' => 'address',
                  'required' => false,
                  'label' => 'Adresse de livraison  ',
                  'required' => false
                 ))
            ->add('address_invoice', 'entity' , array('class' => 'TacTill\CustomerBundle\Entity\Address',
                  'property' => 'address',
                  'required' => false,
                  'label' => 'Adresse de facturaton  ',
                  'required' => false
                 ))


            ->add('color', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'B' => 'Noir', 
                    'W' => 'Blanc'),
                'required' => true,
                "property_path" => false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false
            ))

            ->add('model', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'iPadDeux16Gowifi' => '16 Go Wifi', 
                    'iPadDeux16Gowifi3G' => '16 Go Wifi et 3G', 
                    'iPadNew16Gowifi' => '16GoWifi', 
                    'iPadNew32Gowifi' => '32 Go Wifi',
                    'iPadNew64Gowifi' => '64 Go Wifi',
                    'iPadNew16Gowifi4G' => '16 Go Wifi et 4G',
                    'iPadNew32Gowifi4G' => '32 Go Wifi et 4G',
                    'iPadNew64Gowifi4G' => '64 Go Wifi et 4G'
                    ),
                'required' => true,
                "property_path" => false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false
            ))       

            ->add('stand', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'standsecurity' => 'Sécurité', 
                    'standdesign' => 'Design',
                    'standmobility' => 'Mobilité'
                    ),
                'required' => true,
                "property_path" => false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false
            )) 

            ->add('printer', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'printerB' => 'Noire', 
                    'printerW' => 'Blanche'
                    ),
                'required' => true,
                "property_path" => false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false
            ))  

            ->add('cashDrawer', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'cashDrawerG' => 'Graphite', 
                    'cashDrawerP' => 'Perle'
                    ),
                'required' => true,
                "property_path" => false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false
            )) 

            ->add('app', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'appSmall' => 'S\'abonner à TacTill', 
                    'noApp' => 'Télécharger l\'application plus tard'
                    ),
                'required' => true,
                "property_path" => false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false
            ))                  
        ;                      

    }


    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ticket_packandapptype';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
                'color' => new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Champ vide')),
                'model' => new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Champ vide')),
                'stand' => new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Champ vide')),
                'printer' => new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Champ vide')),
                'cashDrawer' => new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Champ vide')),
                'app' => new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Champ vide')),
        ));

        return array('validation_constraint' => $collectionConstraint);
    }
}
```

**In my controller**

```
public function createOrderAction()
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $requestInArray = $this->getRequest()->request->get('ticket_packandapptype'); 

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form    = $this->createForm(new TicketPackAndAppType());

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

        $form->bind($requestInArray);



        $stand = $requestInArray['stand'];
        $printer = $requestInArray['printer'];
        $cashDrawer = $requestInArray['cashDrawer'];
        $app = $requestInArray['app'];
  }
}
```

I have also test with bindRequest and that is the same problem.

I follow the [Validation without class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class) but i don't where is the mistake.
When i have done the without form class the collection constraints works well.

If you have any idea, explain to me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do smth like this:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

    $form->bindRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        //do your actions with form values
    } else {
       //return form with error messages
       //or do smth else...
    }
```

}

When you call isValid() Symfony tries to checks you daya with your constraint...

Also you should get your data through form:

```
$data = $form->get('your_field_name')->getData();
```

Of course you should do it after binding form from request...